# Доработка программы по изменению регистра символов

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define N 256

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int n = 0;
    char g;
    int caps = 0, white = 0;
    char str[n][10*N];
    while ((g = getc(stdin) != EOF) && g !='\n') {
        fgets(str[n], 10*N, stdin);
        for (int k = 0; k < strlen(str[n]) - 2; k++) {
            if ((str[n][k] != '.' || str[n][k] != '!' || str[n][k] != '?') && str[n][k + 1] == ' ' && isalpha(str[n][k + 2]) && isupper(str[n][k + 2])) {
                str[n][k + 2] = tolower(str[n][k + 2]);
                caps++;
            }
            if (str[n][k] == ' ') white++;
        }
        n++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    if (caps == white) {
        printf("В тексте начинаются с большой буквы все фразы.");
    } else printf("В тексте начинаются с большой буквы не все фразы!");
    printf("\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) puts(str[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Вот я написал программу, которая переписывает все фразы с большой буквы фразами с маленькой и которая решает, все ли фразы начинаются с большой буквы, но при тесте возникли две проблемы:

1. при выводе с каждой строки убирается первый символ;
2. после второго НЕПУСТОГО ввода программа вылетает;

Подскажите причину, пожалуйста.

Comment: `char str[0][10*N];` - ?? "после второго НЕПУСТОГО ввода программа вылетает" - это Вам еще повезло

Comment: как всегда.... тупая ошибка.
но когда я сменил n, допустим на 100, ничего не изменилось. точнее даже ситуация обострилась.
как в этом случае будет правильно поступить?

Comment: "ситуация обострилась" - что это значит?

Comment: стало на первом вылетать

Comment: `str[n][10*N]` это в принципе неверный подход. Выделяйте память динамически

Comment: `str = (char**)realloc(str, (1 + n) * sizeof(char*));
        str[n] = (char*)malloc(10*N * sizeof(char));`

типо так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Куда девается земля, когда в ней дырка?" О.Генри*

---

> при выводе с каждой строки убирается первый символ;

Куда девается символ, прочитанный этим кодом - `g = getc(stdin)`?

```
while (fgets(str[n], 10*N, stdin)) {
  ...
```